# Modal on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, e-commerce

Can you help me with this,

Im working on e-commerce site, so in the cart page i have have one link,

`<a href="https://www.example/nexpageform" title="">BUTTON LINK</a>`

At the moment you are directed to https://www.example/nexpageform when click on this link.
 I want the visitor to stay on the this page and when you click button you got modal and in that modal you get data from next page.

Important thing for me that this Only has to run on desktop, so mobile and tablets has old option and ONLY desktop got modal.

1) Im confused with approach on this, because i need to have modal on desktop and on smaller devices i need to have redirect to another page.

If someone can show me right way or approach I would be grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two anchor tags with different classes or IDs and display them based on CSS media queries.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.desktop-only-link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $('<div />')
      .append('<p>')
      .text('This is a dialog popup')
      .dialog({
        title: 'Your Title Here'
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile-only-link {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop-only-link {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-only-link {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.example/nexpageform" class="mobile-only-link">BUTTON LINK</a>
<a href="#" class="desktop-only-link">BUTTON LINK</a>
```

Comment: thank you for this solution, one more question: on next page when you click button there is one form with data, and how to get that form with data in modal? –

Comment: @MR.Don'tknow I'm not sure what you mean. If you can do an ajax request to the page to grab the data, you can populate it in the modal.

Comment: can i explain to you in inbox or something, if you have some time?

Comment: You can inbox me and I'll see what I can do

Comment: Acutally i cant write in inbox i dont have permision.
So, i will explain here:
There is a cart on shop and you have 3 pages:
1)First page: there is a form and you fill your name, your adress etc,
2)Second page some options, and this modal you write to me.
3) Third page there is this form:
http://pokit.org/get/?b4c58eb0ad8e72790bbe182331fad99e.png
as you can see, in this form are options from previous page(page one)
so when my new modal open, i need to grab this form from third page, and show it. @Bobby Speirs

Comment: Use session storage to store the data on page 1, then retrieve it on page 3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage